# I select a list of place categories in a tableview but in the segue it only sends one

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UiViewController with a tableView, this tableView has a list of places (googlePlaces) that I can select (such as restaurants, cinemas, bar) and then tap a button to go on in the next controller where I expect to see a list of places of the type I have chosen; the problem is that it does not leave places for all the selected categories, for example if I had select cinema, bar and restaurant, one time it shows me only restaurants, the other only the cinemas, in a completely casual manner. Here is my prepare

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == nearbySearchSegueIdentifier {
            let selectedCategories: [QCategoryy] = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.map({ (indexPath) -> QCategoryy in
                return list[indexPath.row] }) ?? []

            if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {

                if let vc : CourseClass2 = segue.destination as? CourseClass2 {
                vc.categories = selectedCategories

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the next viewController

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Social
import AVFoundation


private let resueIdentifier = "MyTableViewCell"


extension UIViewController {
    func present(viewController : UIViewController, completion : (() -> ())? = nil ){
        if let presented = self.presentedViewController {
            presented.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: completion)
            })
        } else {
            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}


class CourseClass2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {





    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager?
    let minimumSpacing : CGFloat = 15 //CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)
    let cellWidth: CGFloat = 250
    let radius = 5000 // 5km
    var categories: [QCategoryy?]? = []
    var currentLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var places: [QPlace] = []
    var isLoading = false
    var response : QNearbyPlacesResponse?
    var rows = 0
    var numberPlaces = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for category in categories! {

         title = category?.name
    }
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        numberPlaces = HomeClass.globalLimit
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        determineMyCurrentLocation()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }



    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

         rows = 0
        tableView.reloadData()
         for category in categories! {

        category?.markView()
    }
}




    @IBAction func refreshTapped(_ sender: Any) {

         rows = 0
        print("numberOfRows Call", self.numberPlaces)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }




    func canLoadMore() -> Bool {
        if isLoading {
            return false
        }

        if let response = self.response {
            if (!response.canLoadMore()) {
                return false
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    func loadPlaces(_ force:Bool) {

        if !force {
            if !canLoadMore() {
                return
            }
        }

        print("load more")
        isLoading = true
         for category in categories! {

        NearbyPlaces.getNearbyPlaces(by: category?.name ?? "food", coordinates: currentLocation!, radius: radius, token: self.response?.nextPageToken, completion: didReceiveResponse)

       }
    }



    func didReceiveResponse(response:QNearbyPlacesResponse?, error : Error?) -> Void {
        if let error = error {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let actionDismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            let actionRetry = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loadPlaces(true)
                }
            })
            alertController.addAction(actionRetry)
            alertController.addAction(actionDismiss)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(viewController: alertController)

            }
        }
        if let response = response {
            self.response = response
            if response.status == "OK" {
                if let placesDownloaded = response.places {
                    places.append(contentsOf: placesDownloaded)
                }

               self.tableView?.reloadData()
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: response.status, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.loadPlaces(true)
                    }
                }))
                 self.present(viewController: alert)
            }
            isLoading = false
        }
        else {
            print("response is nil")
        }
    }




    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        print("numberOfsection Call")
        return 1
    }





    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        print("numberOfRows Call")
        if places.count < self.numberPlaces {

        return  places.count   /*  rows   */
        }
       return self.numberPlaces
    }



    public  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: resueIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell


        let place = places[indexPath.row]
        cell.update(place: place)

        if indexPath.row == places.count - 1 {
            loadPlaces(false)
        }
        print("CellForRow Call")
        return (cell)


    }




     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    })
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLast" , sender: indexPath)

    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {


     return 100
}




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {

            places.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        }

    }
```

What I have to do to make that if had selected more than one category of places, in the tableView of the next viewController shows places for each selected category? (since there is a limit of places that can be shown represented by `numberPlaces = HomeClass.globalLimit` the best solution it would be to have at least one place for each selected category and others added randomly)

EDIT

here where is the indexPathsForSelectedRows

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "CATEGORY_CELL"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
        let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
        let rowIsSelected = selectedIndexPaths != nil && selectedIndexPaths!.contains(indexPath)
       /* cell.accessoryType = rowIsSelected ? .checkmark : .none  */
        cell.accessoryType = list[indexPath.row].isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: does `indexPathsForSelectedRows` has the correct values before using the `map` function?

Comment: @jvrmed i edited the question

Comment: what I meant with my question is, when you click on your segue, if you put a breakpoint at the end of `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`, what is the value of `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?`? You can check it by typing `po tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?` at the debug terminal

Comment: Also, what is the value of `nearbySearchSegueIdentifier`

Comment: @jvrmed ok the value of indexPathsForSelectedRows is correct and the value of the nearbySearchSegueIdentifier is the string ""goToMcourse""

Comment: last question, what is `list`, I can't find it in the code

Comment: @jvrmed  yes  var list : [QCategoryy] = [QCategoryy](), is a var that take from a custom class the various categories of places, i already looked at the value of list and it is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your problem is the architecture of your code. On `loadPlaces` you are iterating through your categories and doing several network calls. Then you append those results to `places` and use `reloadData` to reload the table, but on `cellForRowAt` you call `loadPlaces` again.

Even that you set `isLoading = true` inside `loadPlaces` you have multiple requests going on and all of them set `isLoading = false` at the end. So at some point you will have some unexpected result. You also have some `force` load cases that add up to all that.

Last but not least, since you are calling `self.tableView?.reloadData()` inside a closure, it its possible that its not updating correctly.

**TL;DR**

1. Wrap your `reloadData` around a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block.
2. Implement a queue that serialises your network requests to put some order around your calls. You can use a library like [this](https://github.com/icanzilb/TaskQueue) for example.

   ```
   let queue = TaskQueue()
   for category in categories {
    queue.tasks +=~ { result, next in
        // Add your places request here
    }

    queue.tasks +=! {
        // Reload your table here
    }

    queue.run {
        // check your places array is correct
    }
   }
   ```

Other observations:

1. Your `title` is going to be always the last category on *categories*, since you are not using all the array on `title = category?.name`.
2. To better understand whats going on, try to select only 2 categories and to see if there is a patter on which one is loaded (always the first, or always the second). If there is no pattern at all its because the problem is for sure networking.

Comment: i tried to select only two categories , comes out completely casual

Comment: then you need to rethink how you are loading the data. To fire multiple network requests that modify the same object is a very bad practice. Use the library that I suggested to add your _for category in categories_ loop to enqueue all requests

Comment: i looked at your library, not easy to understand how to do

Comment: where you iterate through your categories

Comment: ok, the really last question, can you give me an example of how i can add the place request and to check if my places array is correct? Sorry for all these question, i'm a beginner and this is the first time that approach to such arguments